# Sci-fi graphic novel from the 90s about immortatlity gained by eating an alien race?

Tags: story-identification, comics, immortality

It was published by a DC imprint, in color and was a 2 part or 3 part series.

All I can remember is:

- One of the protaganists is an uncivil, wealthy sports celebrity and is the guy who eventually lands on an alien planet whose inhabitants are intelligent, with the intention of consuming their flesh in order to become immortal. I think he says they taste like chicken. He plays a sport that's a motorized deathmatch version of polo.
- There is also a rebellion going on by a militant group of genetically spliced human-animal hybrids that is being quashed ruthlessly.
- Most human soldiers seemed to have been bred from test tubes.
- I believe the other protagonist was a female reporter.

Answer (score 3):

Could be Judge Dredd. I think there was an alien race that was hunted because they had a gland that reversed aging. Sorry if it wasn't that comic.